# Adding a spinner from React Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-4, spinner, react-bootstrap

I want to add a spinner to my modal that I am currently on.

```
    <Modal show={modal.show} onHide={onHideModal}>
      <form onSubmit={onImport}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>View Details</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form.Group controlId="csvFile" className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>Import CSV</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="file" accept='.csv, .xls, .xlsx' required className="primary mb-3" name="" onChange={onChangeImportFile} ref={inputFileRef} />
            <Button variant="primary" className="me-2" type="submit" disabled={saving===true ? false : true}>Upload</Button>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-2">
            <Form.Label>Message</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="textarea" readOnly value={fileError} rows={5} />
          </Form.Group>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={clearModal}>
                            Clear
                        </Button>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onHideModal} className="me-auto">
                            Close
                        </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </form>
    </Modal>
```

I want to click submit and it will show the spinner if the data is big. As of right now it looks like it broke but after a while all the data gets sent through.

I tried adding this inside but I am not really sure how to set it up to show the loading when I click the submit button.

```
<Spinner animation="border" role="status" variant="primary">
  <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
</Spinner>
```

Comment: Try it with the standard Bootstrap Spinners. I guess at the moment just to see if it makes a difference. These docs are for Bootstrap 4.2 >> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/spinners/

Comment: @CuteCodeRob I have tried that already but I want it to show only when I click on the submit button, that I could not get to work properly

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think you may have to use some kind of `onclick` function. I can see what you're trying to do and I think it will look really good... I mean if your idea is to show the spinner while the modal is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **useState** variable to change the occurence of spinner

Like, when u click on the submit btn the spinner should show up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add a spinner to your modal that shows while uploading large data:

1. Add loading state variable:

   `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);`
2. Update onImport function:

Set loading to true before starting the upload:

```
const onImport = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission

  setLoading(true); // set loading state to true

  // ... your existing submit logic with data processing and upload ...

  try {
    // ...

    setLoading(false); // set loading state back to false after successful upload

    // ... after successful upload logic like closing modal, showing success message etc.
  } catch (error) {
    setLoading(false); // set loading state back to false on error
    // ... error handling logic

  }
};
```

3. Render the spinner conditionally:

Wrap the button or the modal body with a React.Fragment and render the spinner only when loading is true:

```
<Modal show={modal.show} onHide={onHideModal}>
  <form onSubmit={onImport}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
      <Modal.Title>View Details</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
      <React.Fragment>
        {loading && (
          <Spinner animation="border" role="status" variant="primary">
            <span className="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
          </Spinner>
        )}
        <Form.Group controlId="csvFile" className="mb-3">
          ... // your existing form group content ...
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-2">
          ... // your existing message form group content ...
        </Form.Group>
      </React.Fragment>
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
      ... // your existing modal footer buttons ...
    </Modal.Footer>
  </form>
</Modal>
```

4. (Optional) Disable button while loading:

Add `disabled={loading}` prop to the submit button to prevent further clicks while uploading:

```
<Button variant="primary" className="me-2" type="submit" disabled={loading}>Upload</Button>
```